# Calling method on JavaScript variable passed in using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am passing an  ArrayList object containing addresses from my controller into JavaScript view using Thymeleaf. I am attempting to loop through this list and sending a request to google maps geocding api. My issue is in my loop the .length or .size() are not working on this variable. I do know the object is passing to the view but I dont know why the rest of the code is not running. 
this is my actual JavaScript code.

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">


       /*<![CDATA[*/
//list of locations passed from controller to view using thymeleaf
var locations = [[${locations}]];
// .length not working on variable
console.log(locations.size());
var size = locations.length;
//loop through user locations .length and .size() not working
for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++){
    console.log(locations[i])
    //make call to api using location
```

and here is what i am seeing when i inspect the code

```
       /*<![CDATA[*/
//list of locations passed from controller to view using thymeleaf
var locations = ["12 Main St bonne terre mo 63628"," 100 division st bonne terre mo 63628","4345 fyler ave st louis mo 63116","12 Main St bonne terre mo 63628"];
// .length method not running on variable
console.log(locations.size());
var size = locations.length;
//loop through user locations .length method not working
for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++){
    console.log(locations[i])
    //make call to api to get activity.location coordinates
```

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +

i can see that my list of addresses is being passed in but do not know why i cant get the length of the list for my loop.

I have tried

```
 for(var i=0; i < [[${locations.size()}]]; i++){
    console.log([[${locations[i]}]])
```

but i is not recognized and is not pulling anything out of this list. 
here is page inspection.

```
//loop through user locations .length and .size() not working
for(var i=0; i < 4; i++){
    console.log(
```

[documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(locations)`?

Comment: I'm getting an array with a list of addresses but using any method or property is like .length or .size() is not being recognized. I know it is something to do with Thymeleaf not accepting Javascript local variables but cant seem to figure out how i would complete a loop without a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix Javascript and Thymeleaf variables. In this code for example:

```
for(var i=0; i < [[${locations.size()}]]; i++){
    console.log([[${locations[i]}]])
```

You are defining `i` in the javascript and expecting Thymeleaf to know what `i` mean in the next line of code: `console.log([[${locations[i]}]])`. `i` is undefined, so nothing is printed out.  Since you already have your list of locations at this point:

```
var locations = [[${locations}]];
```

From then on, you should only be dealing with javascript variables.  This code will work:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  var locations = /*[[${locations}]]*/ [];

  for(var i=0; i < locations.length; i++){
    console.log(locations[i]);
  }

  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input this is actually what i have put into my code but even though im putting that list into a JavaScript variable locations.length or locations.size() is not working for the loop. Its as if even though i have it in that variable its still seen as thymeleaf.

Comment: I tested this out with a list of data and verified that it worked, so there is something else going on then.  Can you just directly paste the code in a separate block and just verify that single block of code?  As for `locations.size()` -- that is not a JavaScript function so that will never work.

Comment: i was able to find a solution i did not use .size() used .length. i do have the code posted like what you had in my first snippit above, there were a lot of comments so it probably made it confusing for you to read, sorry. i dont know if it is the version of thymeleaf but i had to use a th;for each loop and push each element of the list into an empty list and then work with it that way. i posted solution i found below thanks so much for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

using this code i was able to get the passed in element and put into a list and loop over the list.

```
           /*<![CDATA[*/
//list of locations passed from controller to view using thymeleaf






var locations = [];

/*[# th:each="n : ${locations}"]*/

    locations.push("[(${n})]");
    /*[/]*/
```

/*]]>*/

```
//loop through user locations 
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
```

axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
        params:{

```
     address:locations[i],
      key:'AIzaSyC0_mpWB_nOm_gsjWwbgD_2EXYsnYTD6Jg'
    }
  })


  //using response from api to add markers to map
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;



    addMarker({lat:lat,lng:lng});
 })
 }
 }
```